# Javascript document.location.reload does not work

Tags: javascript

When I used `document.location.reload()` as in case1 below, it doesn't work. But when I add an `alert()` as in case2, it works. I want to figure out what happened?

```
//case1: does not work
document.location='rc_msg.php?remove=0';
document.location.reload(); 
//case2: work
document.location='rc_msg.php?remove=0';
document.location.reload(); 
alert("OK!!");
```

---

I did not notice I entered '=' twice, I am sorry about that.
I had tried the opinion solution below, but they did not work neither

Comment: `document.location` is an object, you're trying to compare it to a string...

Comment: Your code makes no sense...What are you trying to do exactly? SHow your real code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to test the location (double equals) or assign it the new location (single equals)?

Try:

```
document.location='rc_msg.php?remove=0';
document.location.reload();
```

Comment: And what you typed makes no sense...How can you set the location and reload? ;)

Answer (score 1):

document.location returns a string, now deprecated and replaced by document.URI.

**window.location** (or **location**) is an object with a reload method.